# Serialization among numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have very large numbers like `765478865543`.

I want to check if there is matching between the numbers or sequenced.

Is it possible to do that in `sql sever`?

for example:
I have list like this

> 765478865543,765478865544,765478865666,4553355667533,... ,

I would like to know if there any serialization for each numbers among other numbers , and if there exist serialization , is it possible to account the matching numbers?!

the expected result:
number                       has serialization                   serialized with
765478865543                         yes                           765478865544

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Show expected result please.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want. You can find continuous numbers as the below:

```
DECLARE @MockTable TABLE (Id DECIMAL)
INSERT INTO @MockTable        
VALUES  
(765478865543),
(765478865544),
(765478865545),
(765478865550),
(765478865551),
(765478865561),
(765478865581),
(765478865583),
(765478865584)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) RowId       
    FROM 
        @MockTable
)

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        MIN(Id) [Start],
        MAX(Id) [End]
    FROM
        CTE
    GROUP BY
        Id - CTE.RowId
) A
WHERE
    A.Start <> A.[End]
```

Result:

```
Start                                   End
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
765478865543                            765478865545
765478865550                            765478865551
765478865583                            765478865584
```